# How to minus 2 month in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

My requirement is to make this query :

```
SELECT DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```

Minus by 2 months and the date should be stayed in 1.

Comment: What is the expected result ?  and which version of `Sql server` you are using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `DATEADD` function on top of your existing query

```
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,-2,DATEADD(M, DATEDIFF(M, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) --2016-05-01 00:00:00.000
```

If you are using `SQL SERVER 2012+` the use `EOMONTH` function

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-3)) --2016-05-01
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, the following gets the first day of this month:

```
select cast(dateadd(day, 1 - day(getdate()), getdate()) as date)
```

For last month:

```
select dateadd(month, -1, cast(dateadd(day, 1- day(getdate()), getdate()) as date))
```

In SQL Server 2012+, you can also do:

```
select dateadd(month, -2, datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1)
```

The use of adding months to a zero time is a hack before SQL Server had better date time functions.

Comment: @Prdp . . . I was interrupted in the middle of writing the answer and submitted it too early.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, i've tested this `SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,-2,DATEADD(M, DATEDIFF(M, 0, GETDATE()), 0))` and it  works in sql server 2014 thanks @Prdp and @Gordon Linoff